# How do you make a glass cube?

Tags: rendering, materials, eevee-render-engine

I've watched a couple of tutorials on youtube but none of them give me the result I want.

My cubes always turn out like this where one side is transparent and others are not, I want them to look like the cubes from the PS2 intro. Below are the settings I added to the cubes material and what I want it to look like

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not at all, I messed with those settings before and still no result.

Comment: I tried that, still nothing

Comment: You have to enable screen space refraction (in the settings) and the same in the out put menu also tell me if you need any image on how to do it

Comment: Yea an image would be nice @Nxdhin2005

Answer (score 1):

First enable screen space reflection in settings of the material[image]

then in the render properties enable screen space reflection and then enable refraction in the screen space reflection tab...[image]

Don't forget to change the ior to 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Your IOR is wrong. IOR of typical glass is 1.5

Comment: It makes no difference