# Eevee. Why changes in the HDRI are not shown through the glass window?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, glass

I set up my glass texture, but find out that if I move the HDRI image, the changes are not shown through the glass windows.  In another word, I'm stuck with the view from when I set up the glass texture.  Is there a way to have the changes to the HDRI show through the glass panes, like the glass panes are truly transparent?  Thank you!

[image]

Please see the shader nodes. I'm using EEVEE, and the screen space refraction is enabled in the material setting of the glass. I did find a different set of shader nodes for glass from one of the answers on this site. The glass did "behave" in a transparent manner, nonetheless if anyone can modify the shader nodes I posted to make the glass see through.

[image]

Comment: please edit your image and tell us what render engine you are using, and show an image of the shader nodes you are using for the glass.

Comment: If you are using EEVEE check whether you have screen space refraction enabled in the material settings of the glass

Comment: For Cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47851/how-can-i-make-a-more-realistic-glass-shader

Comment: Please see the shader nodes.  I'm using EEVEE, and the screen space refraction is enabled in the material setting of the glass.  I did find a different set of shader nodes for glass from one of the answers on this site.  The glass did "behave" in a transparent manner, nonetheless if anyone can modify the shader nodes I posted to make the glass see through, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Eevee doesn't need the glass hack of blender guru. That node setup is for cycles. Just use a principled BSDF with roughness zero and transmission 1 and again **have u enabled screen space refraction ?

Comment: See my answer here- https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185646/how-do-you-make-a-glass-cube/185655#185655

Comment: Thank you!  Yes.  I have enabled screen space refraction.